# change the number of colors in matplotlib stylesheets

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am plotting several graphs with matplotlib for a publication and I need that all have the same style. Some graphs have more than 6 categories and I have noticed that, by default, it does not plot more than 6 different colours. 7 or more and I start to have repeated colours.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('seaborn-muted')

df2= pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,8))
df2.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.legend(fontsize=13,loc=1)
plt.show()
```

There is probably a cognitive reason not to include more than 6 different colours, but if I need to, How can I do it? I have tried different stylesheets (seaborn, ggplot, classic) and all have seem to have the same "limitation".

Do I need to change the colormap/stylesheet? Ideally, I would like to use a qualitative colormap (there is no order in the categories that I am plotting) and use a pre-existing one... I am not very good choosing colours.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))

df2= pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,8))
df2.plot(kind='bar',color=colors, stacked=True)
plt.legend(fontsize=13,loc=1)
```

this is basically copied from [Plotting with more colors in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995352/plotting-with-more-colors-in-matplotlib). check the document of [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) and its [example page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

Comment: It works! because I wanted a qualitative colormap (jet is not, and it is seriously discouraged) I changed it to "Paired" one of the qualitative color maps available in matplotlib  http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html

Answer (score 4):

By default, matplotlib will cycle through a series of six colors. If you want to change the default colors (or number of colors), you can use [`cycler`](http://matplotlib.org/cycler/) to loop through the colors you want instead of the defaults.

```
from cycler import cycler

% Change the default cycle colors to be red, green, blue, and yellow
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']))
```

[demo here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html)

A better way is just to manually specify plot colors when you create your `plot` so that not every plot you make has to use the same colors.

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], 'r')
plt.plot([4,5,6], 'g')
plt.plot([7,8,9], 'b')
plt.plot([10,11,12], 'y')
```

Or you can change the color after creation

```
h = plt.plot([1,2,3])
h.set_color('r')
```

Comment: Please note that the list of colors passed to `cycler()` can both be of arbitrary length, and in any format supported by [`matplotlib.colors`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors). For example, I have this in my `matplotlibrc`: `cycler("color", "348ABD, 7A68A6, A60628, 467821, CF4457, 188487, E24A33")` - blue, purple, red, green, pink, turquoise, orange. The hex colors may or may not include a `#` hash, and can be a comma-separated string (like mine) or a list. You can also use [X11 colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names).